# Forcing axis units in Excel 2013 plots, being written after minimum bound of axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013, axis

I have a plot, drawn in Excel 2013. The data begins from almost 0.9 to almost 5.1. I want the x axis to be written from 1 to 5 and to show the data from 0.9 to 5.1.

Upon my best effort, I could set the minimum and maximum bound to 0.9 and 5.1 (based on which shows my entire data) and set the major unit to be 1.
But it shows the units as : {0.9, 1.9, 2.9, 3.9, 4.9}. How can I keep the bound while setting the units to be {1,2,3,4,5}?

Comment: You should set the lower bound of the axis to 0.  It is considered bad practice in all of the fields I've worked in (Science, Finance, Engineering, Medical, Marketing) to not include 0 on the axis.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro Tnx! But now in my case, doing this has preference for the work.

Comment: You can use a graphics editing program to "break" the axis since Excel doesn't have a function for it, but axis numbering in Excel will always start at the lower bound.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro Tnx so much. I asked hoping to find an Excel-based way which seems not to exist.

Comment: How do you want to treat your data that falls outside of the 1-5 range of your axis?  Do you want it shown, but outside of the lines, or not shown at all?

Comment: @dav As I explained, begins almost from 0.9 and ends in almost 5.1 and I also limited my x axis to that boundary. So, everything is shown (as I want). The problem is the axis units are shown as {0.9, 1.9, 2.9, 3.9, 4.9}.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro: I agree, with a caveat, that it depends on the story you are trying to tell, and how you tell it. You should not change the axis to be misleading, but the axis range can be used to highlight min and max vaiues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel won't do this using any of the default settings, but it can be done using a "helper" series.

1. Format the Horizontal/X Axis for No Labels and No Ticks
2. Add an additional series to your chart using the following values (and change it to a XY/Scatter type, if that's not what your chart is).

   - X Values: {1,2,3,4,5}
   - Y Values: {0,0,0,0,0}
3. Format your new series to be:

   - Marker Type = + (this will replace your ticks)
   - Line Color = No Line (this will allow your grid line to show, since you have a gap before and after your series values (0.9-1.0 and 5.0-5.1)
   - Marker Line Color-set to match your gridline color
   - Marker Line Style-set Line Width to match your gridline width
4. Add Data Labels to your series

   - Label Contains = X Value
   - Label Position = Below

In this sample, everything in red is based upon the "helper" series:

[image: Offset Grid]

If you want vertical gridlines aligned to your ticks, you can use vertical error bars set for the vertical scale.

Comment: Would the down voter please give me some constructive criticism, so I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 1):

@mr-moscaro says that starting an axis at zero is mandatory, but this isn't universally true. However, in your case, you haven't mentioned why you must start the axis above zero when the fraction of the axis between zero and the minimum you want is such a small amount.

Here's an alternative. I've plotted some arbitrary points with X values between 0.9 and 5.1 in a simple scatter plot, with the axis ranging between 0 and 6, which is what Excel picked out all by itself, and which to me seems perfectly reasonable.

However, to show only the labels between 1 and 5, I have applied the following custom number format to the X axis:

```
[>5]"";[<1]"";0;
```

Basically, is says if the value is greater than five, show "" instead of the value, if the value is less than one, show "" instead of the value, and otherwise show the value with no decimal digits.

And here is the chart:

[image]

IMNSHO, suppressing the labels at 0 and 6 does in no way improve the chart.